# Get the post value of an input within a foreach with razor

Tags: javascript, razor

Im trying to make a list of elements in which you post an id. The "e" var is just a list of objects.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < e.Count; i++)
{
<li>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@e[i].id"/> 
    <a onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();">@e[i].name</a>
</li>
}
```

The problem that i got is that im trying to get the value from the input selected and if i give them the same name i get the same value everytime, when they should be different. 
I tried to mix razor + javascript to get this working but i'm having trouble with this so i would like to any easier approach to this.
What i intend to to is to get the value with a

```
Request["name"];
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have to use the different name for the `name` attribute also..

Comment: And also please explain what is ur pblm with `Request`.

Comment: But by being generated in this way dinamically the name stays the same, i could do something like name["id-@i"], that actually works for creating different names but how can i know which one was the one being inputed?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your values will be available in `Request["id"]` as a comma-separated list. That is because you have multiple elements in the same form with the same `name` attribute value.

You can process the values on the server individually by using the `string.Split` method:

```
if(IsPost && !Request["id"].IsEmpty()){
    foreach(var id in Request["id"].Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
       // process the id
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i could do that, but the problem is that i want to identify which one is being pressed.

Comment: Which 'what' was being pressed?